# Is it possible to export/import Project.params within SSIS?

Tags: ssis

Does SSIS 2012 allow to export settings of a project located into `Project.params` for a further import into another project?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply copy and replace the Project.params file in your new project with the file from the existing project. This obviously overwrites any existing project parameters. If you have need, you can patch the two XML files together just add/remove `SSIS:Parameter` tags as required.